# jquery mobile silentScroll animate

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

I am using the jquery mobile silentScroll to go from one div element to another.
The silentScroll is working. But it is a 'jump' from the first element to the next.
I want a transition or animation down scroll.
I am using the following code.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

  $( "#scrolldown" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
    // find this element's offset position
    target = $("#helloworld").get(0).offsetTop;
    // scroll the page to that position
    return $.mobile.silentScroll(target);
  });

});
```

I have searched but I cannot find a solution to animate down to the target element.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of using `.silentScroll` is to *scroll without triggering* `scroll` event. If you want to animate scrolling, use the below, but this will trigger `scroll` event.

```
$("html, body").animate({ "scrollTop" : target }, 500); /* 500 is speed in ms */
```

Another note, use *page events* in jQuery Mobile rather than using `.ready()`.

Comment: Thank you @Omar. My problem is solved. I did not catch that .silentScroll purpose is to not scroll or animate. I am new to jQuery Mobile. Obviously, I need a lot more reading to do.

Comment: @user3056349 you're welcome. You can use `.silentScroll` if you want to scroll without triggering `scroll` event. It's useful in some occasions. Good luck :)

Comment: This does not work in Chrome Developer Tools in device mode, but I don't know about mobile devices.

Comment: @Omar, you're right. This example with `"html, body"` selector works. But if I try to apply it on any other element (for ex. jQuery Mobile page), it does not. Anyway, in my case I can proceed with "html, body". Thanks!

Comment: @alkaponey I have many other answers/examples using this method http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1771795+scrollTop